# Analyzing database schema. You r database projects will be ready after X Operations are completed - VS 2015 Pro lack of performance

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-project

I've been experimenting lack of performance when I open a "specific"solution with Data Base projects with VS 2015 Pro, I found some answers here but non of them solved my problem, maybe because most of them are of VS 2010-2013.

**Environment**

- Solution with three data base projects
- Sql Server 2012 Enterprise (local environment)
- Visual studio 2015 Pro

**Additional info**

- I started seeing this lack of performance two days ago, before this process ended in like 2 minutes (fast enough for the size of the data bases)
- I reviewed recent changes to this solution, there's nothing obvious.
- I deleted the dbml files from the solution, It didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score -1):

The update 3 of Visual studio 2015 solve the problem.
You can get it from here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

Answer (score -1):

1. Access your project folder and look for **.dbmdl** file and delete it.
2. Right Click on your project > Properties
3. Project Settings > Database Settings
4. Uncheck "Auto Create Statistics" and "Auto Update Statistics"
5. Click OK > then Save.

Rebuild your project and it should work now.

Comment: This is not helping in any way, those are database properties you can also find in the Options section of the Database Properties dialog (using SSMS), meaning if you change those settings and publish the project, you'll change the settings on the published database, potentially decreasing performances in the long run.

There is no way to avoid the schema being analyzed. Period.